# get-adcomputer error: "Invalid Enumeration Context" when running powershell script

Tags: active-directory, powershell

We're switching to WDS for deployment, so I'm writing a powershell script that will ping a computer and if it responds, get its MAC address and set the netbootGUID field in Active directory. It runs and works...for a while and then returns:

> Get-ADComputer : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration
> context.
> At \Path\To\Scripts\setNetbootGUIDremoteComputers.ps1:3 char:15
>
> - get-adcomputer <<<<  -Filter * -searchbase "OU=Somehwere,DC=My,DC=AD,DC=TLD"
>   -ResultSetSize $null | foreach-object {
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ADException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer

This is the script:

```
import-module ActiveDirectory

get-adcomputer -Filter * -searchbase "OU=Somewhere,DC=MY,DC=AD,DC=TLD" -ResultSetSize $null | foreach-object {

    $strComputer = $_.Name
    $ping = new-object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
    $Reply = $ping.send($strComputer)
    
    if ($Reply.status –eq “Success”){
            $colItems = GWMI -cl "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration" -name "root\CimV2" -comp $strComputer -filter "IpEnabled = TRUE"
    
            ForEach ($objItem in $colItems) {
                $MAC = $objItem.MacAddress.Replace(":", "") 
                Write-Host "Machine Name: " $strComputer
                Write-Host "MAC Address:" $MAC                          
                [guid]$nbGUID = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-$MAC"        
                $comp = get-adcomputer $strComputer -Properties netbootGUID
                $comp.netbootGUID = $nbGUID.ToByteArray()
                set-adcomputer -Instance $comp
                write-output "$strComputer" | out-file -filePath c:\somewhere\guidSet.txt -append
            }
    }
    else {
        write-output "$strComputer" | out-file -filePath c:\somewhere\offline.txt -append
    }
    $Reply = ""


     
}
```

I have no idea why I'm getting that error or what it means. My GoogleFu is failing me today.

Comment: Try wrapping it in a [Try/Catch statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315350.aspx) ala Ben's example in my question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/212116/error-when-adding-bulk-users-in-ad-with-powershell-script/212237#212237).  It might give you more info to troubleshoot since it's running for a bit before choking.  It might be just a single result that's causing it to crap out on you.

Comment: Curious.  How many objects is this likely to return?

Comment: Do you know which computer is throwing this error? I suspect a permissions issue.  I've run trough over 2000 of our machines and have only seen the `"An exception occurred during a Ping request."` error.

Comment: @uSlackr thousands

Comment: @jscott Unfortunately, no. But it seemed to happen at different positions each time. I ended up just creating sub-OUs and running it each of them with 1-2k objects a piece. This environment doesn't exist anymore, so I can't really follow up :(

Comment: Sorry to respond to an old thread - for some reason it bubbled up and I didni't look at the thread date.

Comment: It's OK. It bubbled up because it didn't have an accepted answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like I'll be able to re-create the problem since the environment in question has changed substantially.

Comment: @MDMarra Doh, I didn't even look at the date on this. :) Sorry. Glad to hear it's working now.

Comment: For anyone else looking, I found an answer and will let someone else write it up: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never resolved this. I ended up making OUs under the larger container and running this against 1k accounts at a time.

Unfortunately, this will remain a mystery, since this environment no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

NB:  I'm not a PS guru

My google fu turned up the [following link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/80ea7fac-8463-4ac1-af95-bfeab21343b6/).

In short, I think it has something to do with your `-ResultSetSize $null` portion of the script.  In the link, the OP used `-notlike "*"`instead of the `-eq "$Null"`

Maybe play with that portion of the script and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortunately, the -ResultSetSize isn't a filter, so the -notlike switch doesn't apply to it :( The get-help page for get-adcomputer says that -eq $NULL is the correct way to say that there is no max result size. Thanks for the try though.

Answer (score 1):

I like the get-adcomputer and quest-active directory commands for cases where i need a lot of information on a server, but otherwise stick with the active-directory commands `dsquery` and `dsget`, because I find the `get-adcomputer` and especially the `quest` commands unnecessarily slow, though something may be requiring you not to use these `ds` commands.  If you do have access to these commands, this might be worth a shot, even if it just gives you a different error message, as it by-passes the use of get-adcomputer and existing method of determining ping-ability ( kind of Mickey-Mouse, but sometimes this way provides additional information ) -

```
dsquery computer ou=Somewhere,dc=My,dc=AD,dc=TLD | ?{$_ -imatch "cn=([^,]+,),"} | % {
    $your_computer = $Matches[1]
    $cannot_ping_computer = $false

    # similarly for the ping command, but should be it's own little function
    ping $your_computer | ?{$_ -imatch "\s*Packets: Sent = (\d+), Received = (\d+)" }|% {
      # or whatever conditions you find satisfactory
      if ($Matches[1] -ne $Matches[2]) $cannot_ping_computer = $true
    }
    if ( $cannot_ping_computer ) {
      #command to jump to next element in pipe, I cannot recall >.<      
    }
    # rest of your code...
}
```

Been out of work for past couple months, and have no access to a Windows machine, so the code is off the top of my head, but I hope it works for you.  Seems right.

I hope you solved the problem, but if not, I hope this can help in some way.

Good luck! :)

Comment: I really don't think that running `dsquery computer -limit 0` is going to be faster than running a PowerShell query with a filter. The AD has well over 10k computer objects in it. Your implementation would return a result for every single computer and then evaluate whether or not it belongs in the set. I appreciate the attempt, but I'm looking for a pure native PowerShell implementation.

Comment: Mark, you are correct, and I updated the suggestion to filter as your task requires.  This should eleviate concerns of efficiency on the 10k objects.  I think the only advantage is handling small strings instead of objects with unused data, and that you can potentially get alternative information on the issue and, or, by-pass the current issue.  Either way, good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try playing with the ResultPageSize parameter based on this [post](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/p/8060/13162.aspx).  Perhaps setting it to a few hundred results at a time.

Comment: The site can't be reached.?
Anyway, does the -ResultPageSize will only limit the result up to that amount we specify not the complete result?